# How to specify "realm" parameter for dotnetopenauth lib

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth, realm

I try to do OAuth (version 1.0) request authorization on the server and using DotNetOpenAuth library for this. The server has some troubles with getting authorization parameters through the Authorization HTTP header and request parameter "realm" to be required. I have no idea how to specify it in DotNetOpenAuth library. Any help will be very much appreciated!

regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  At least not through the public API included in the shipping version of DotNetOpenAuth.  Please jump over to http://dotnetopenauth.uservoice.com/ and submit a feature request detailing what you need.

Useful details might include whether you need the same value for the realm parameter for all your requests, vs. needing to customize it for individual requests.